# Tensorflow reproducibility for the following script?

Tags: tensorflow

For the following script https://github.com/abdulfatir/prototypical-networks-tensorflow/blob/master/ProtoNet-MiniImageNet-v2.ipynb when I add the statements -
`tf.set_random_seed(1)` and `np.random.seed(1)` at the beginning of the script, I still get different results from different runs. I am not sure where the extra randomness is coming from.

Can anybody help me out?